# Signal output arduino

Tags: arduino, output, signals

I want to ouput a signal via an arduino. I have the time and voltage amplitude of the signal and now I want to output this voltage with the arduino. I could not find a way to do it or if it is even possible. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Arduino has only a [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)-output. So your PWM is a pulse signal with a time of 0V and 5V output. So you are not able to set a specific analog value to your output without additional hardware circuit (for example this [PWM converter](http://www.instructables.com/id/Analog-Output-Convert-PWM-to-Voltage/) --> lowpass). Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191742/how-is-a-pwm-signal-converted-to-sine-using-a-transformer) for other descriptions.